# Dynamic Proxies causing object.child = null object to fail?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've noticed some odd behaviour I can't explain, probably to do with dynamic proxies because I can't recreate it with simple object instancing, but more bizarrely is the `?` operator behaviour that I tried to use to get round it.

I have two simple objects:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I find a `Parent` object using a `DbContext` method e.g.

```
Parent parentToUpdate = _context.Parent.Find(1);
```

This object comes equipped with a populated child already, say with Id 22, generated as a `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxy`

I then have a new child object which becomes a null because it wasn't found in the database, using the same DbContext:

```
Child newChild = _context.Child.Find(999); // returns null
```

I then try to overwrite the `parentToUpdate` object's child with the `newChild` object:

```
parentToUpdate.Child = newChild;
```

This intermittently doesn't work - The `parentToUpdate.Child` doesn't become null.

**Question 1 - Why doesn't this work?**
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with dynamic proxies.

I then thought ok, I'll check for a null first:

```
if(newChild == null)
{
    parentToUpdate.Child = null;
}
else
{
    parentToUpdate.Child = newChild;
}
```

and that `if else` format **always** works.

But actually I only tried it that way because before that, I tried it the concise way, using `?`

```
parentToUpdate.Child = newChild == null ? null : newChild;
```

And this also often doesn't work.

**Question 2 How can this statement fail?** It doesn't assign `null` nor the `newChild` object (which is also null!) - Is this statement not basically an `if else` statement?

I noticed this while testing in debug config, but actually stepping through the code it seems the behaviour happens a little less often.

**What is going on here?**

Comment: Why do you have nullable primary keys? That's highly uncommon and it may be related to this issue.

Comment: In reality they only exist in a few of my ViewModels, can't remember why I implemented them but I might revisit, see if I can get rid and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Think it was something to do with default values on dropdownlists in a viewmodel...

Comment: First see what happens if you make then non-nullable.

Comment: non-nullable makes no difference!

Comment: What's very annoying is that stepping through an `if else` statement works EVERY time. But when running normally it only works sometimes. The other two methods sometimes don't even work when stepping through. It must be dynamic proxies.